# Three.js Dom event ( linkify.js)

Tags: javascript, three.js

I can't make it work. on the console, it says that the click event work,
but i cant link the sphere with an url.
Iam using last version of three.js

here is my code : `

```
// once everything is loaded, we run our Three.js stuff.
$(function () {
var geometry, material, mesha;

    var clock = new THREE.Clock();
    var raycaster;
    var stats = initStats();

    // create a scene, that will hold all our elements such as   objects, cameras and lights.
    var scene = new THREE.Scene();

    // create a camera, which defines where we're looking at.
    var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);


    // create a render and set the size
    var webGLRenderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    webGLRenderer.setClearColor(new THREE.Color(0x000, 1.0));
    webGLRenderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    webGLRenderer.shadowMapEnabled = true;

    // position and point the camera to the center of the scene
    camera.position.x = 100;
    camera.position.y = 10;
    camera.position.z = 1000;
    camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0));


    var camControls = new THREE.FirstPersonControls(camera);
    camControls.lookSpeed = 0.4;
    camControls.movementSpeed = 30;
    camControls.noFly = true;
    camControls.lookVertical = true;
    camControls.constrainVertical = false;
    camControls.verticalMin = 0.0;
    camControls.verticalMax = 1.0;
    camControls.lon = -150;
    camControls.lat = 120;


    var ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x383838);
    scene.add(ambientLight);

    // add spotlight for the shadows
    var spotLight = new THREE.SpotLight(0xffffff);
    spotLight.position.set(100, 140, 130);
    spotLight.intensity = 10;
    scene.add(spotLight);

    // add the output of the renderer to the html element
    $("#WebGL-output").append(webGLRenderer.domElement);

    // call the render function
    var step = 0;


    // setup the control gui
    var controls = new function () {
        // we need the first child, since it's a multimaterial


    }


var domEvents   = new THREEx.DomEvents(camera, webGLRenderer.domElement)

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//      add an object and make it move                  //
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////  
var geometry    = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 100.5 )
var material    = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial()
var mesh    = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material )
scene.add( mesh ) 

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//      linkify our cube                        //
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

var url = 'http://jeromeetienne.github.io/threex/'
THREEx.Linkify(domEvents, mesh, url)


domEvents.addEventListener(mesh, 'click', function(event){
    console.log('you clicked on mesh', mesh)

}, false)


    var gui = new dat.GUI();


    var mesh;
var onProgress = function ( xhr ) {
                if ( xhr.lengthComputable ) {
                    var percentComplete = xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100;
                    console.log( Math.round(percentComplete, 2) + '%  downloaded' );
                }
            };
            var onError = function ( xhr ) { };




var mtlLoader = new THREE.MTLLoader();
        mtlLoader.setBaseUrl( '../assets/models/door/' );
            mtlLoader.setPath( '../assets/models/door/' );
            mtlLoader.load( 'door.mtl', function( materials ) {

                materials.preload();

                var objLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
                objLoader.setMaterials( materials );
                objLoader.setPath( '../assets/models/door/' );
                objLoader.load( 'door.obj', function ( object ) {

                    object.position.y =  -1;
                       object.scale.x   = 2;
         object.scale.y = 2;
          object.scale.z    = 2;

                    scene.add( object );

                }, onProgress, onError );

            });



// floor

            geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry( 2000, 2000, 100, 100 );
        geometry.rotateX( - Math.PI / 2 );

            for ( var i = 0, l = geometry.vertices.length; i < l; i ++ ) {

                var vertex = geometry.vertices[ i ];
                vertex.x += Math.random() * 20 - 10;
                vertex.y += Math.random() * 3;
                vertex.z += Math.random() * 20 - 10;

            }

            for ( var i = 0, l = geometry.faces.length; i < l; i ++ ) {

                var face = geometry.faces[ i ];
                face.vertexColors[ 0 ] = new THREE.Color().setHSL( Math.random() * 0.3 + 0.5, 0.75, Math.random() * 0.25 + 0.75 );
                face.vertexColors[ 1 ] = new THREE.Color().setHSL( Math.random() * 0.3 + 10.5, 0.75, Math.random() * 0.25 + 0.75 );
                face.vertexColors[ 2 ] = new THREE.Color().setHSL( Math.random() * 0.3 + 0.5, 0.75, Math.random() * 0.25 + 0.75 );

            }

            material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { vertexColors: THREE.VertexColors } );

            mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
            scene.add( mesh );





    function setCamControls() {

    }

    render();

    function setRandomColors(object, scale) {
        var children = object.children;

        if (children && children.length > 0) {
            children.forEach(function (e) {
                setRandomColors(e, scale)
            });
        } else {
            // no children assume contains a mesh
            if (object instanceof THREE.Mesh) {

                object.material.color = new THREE.Color(scale(Math.random()).hex());
                if (object.material.name.indexOf("building") == 0) {
                    object.material.emissive = new THREE.Color(0x444444);
                    object.material.transparent = true;
                    object.material.opacity = 0.8;
                }
            }
        }
    }


    function render() {
        stats.update();
        var delta = clock.getDelta();

        if (mesh) {
            //   mesh.rotation.y+=0.006;
        }


        camControls.update(delta);
        webGLRenderer.clear();
        // render using requestAnimationFrame
        requestAnimationFrame(render);
        webGLRenderer.render(scene, camera)
    }

    function initStats() {

        var stats = new Stats();
        stats.setMode(0); // 0: fps, 1: ms

        // Align top-left
        stats.domElement.style.position = 'absolute';
        stats.domElement.style.left = '0px';
        stats.domElement.style.top = '0px';

        $("#Stats-output").append(stats.domElement);

        return stats;
    }
});
```

can somebody help ? have you an idea?
Iam quite a newbie...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution:**

Get the latest version of DomEvents (https://github.com/jeromeetienne/threex.domevents) which has been updated to r74 right now.

---

**Explaination:**

This one took me some time to figure out, lets see whats going on:

`THREEx.DomEvents` is internally using the `THREE.Raycaster` to detect when the mouse is pointing on meshes. `ThreeJS` changed lately the behavior of the raycaster to not intersect with invisible meshes anymore ([source](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/commit/05b98867277dceb0b7701650c4ca40d54f0c0b8a)). Yeah well I dont care, my click event is fireing you say?

Lets have a look at `Linkyfy`:

```
THREEx.Linkify  = function(domEvents, mesh, url, withBoundingBox){
    withBoundingBox = withBoundingBox !== undefined ? withBoundingBox : true
    // create the boundingBox if needed
    if( withBoundingBox ){
        var boundingBox = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.CubeGeometry(1,1,1), new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
            wireframe   : true
        }))
        boundingBox.visible = false
        boundingBox.scale.copy(size)
        mesh.add(boundingBox)   
    }
// ...
```

The fourth parameter `withBoundingBox` is evaluating to `true` if you dont supply it. Linkify is then creating a "bounding box mesh" which is invisible and *wrapping around* your mesh you want to linkify. The raycaster does not trigger an intersection anymore and there you have it. To allow the raycaster to detect an intersection although the boundingBox-object is invisible, set only the meshs materials visibility to false and not the mesh:
`boundingBox.material.visible = false`

Comment: everything is fine . it works. If you can explain (in detail) what was the problem, please do. 
you save me. thank you a lot . If you need some thing I will be proud to help you. . merci beaucoup.

Comment: The explaination is right there below the solution. I fixed this and created a PR on github, which is why the latest version works :-) If this solved your problem please accept this answer to mark this question as solved.

Comment: I have notice that it dont' work with an effect ( ascii effect )    do you know why ?

Comment: I dont know what you mean by "ascii effect", but it sounds like out of scope for this question. To talk about it you should open a new one.